# Any cloud mobile device provider whose devices I can embed on my website

Tags: android, ios, virtualization, amazon, android-emulator

I am looking for a cloud device provider who gives you the ability to embed the device on my website. I need for both Android and iOS device.

I checked Aws Device farm but couldn't figure out if the devices they give can be embedded on my website.

Comment: It's not an answer, but maybe it help: I cannot imagine that such tools for testing devices have an embedding function. Also the image quality and performance of these tools is usually quite bad. If it's a website, maybe you can just embed an iFrame into a device image? Or you use https://github.com/c0bra/deviceframe if you only need images.
But I am curious if someone has a suggestion for you.

Comment: @Markus Thanks for your comment. I too believe that no one provides their devices for embedding. Since having our own farm of devices is out of the question, l will probably open the provider's device in a browser on a remote machine and use noVNC to embed the portion with the phone on my website. For device-frame, I can definitely try your linked project. Thanks